# How do I use pointers interacting with c(library)

Tags: swift, pointers

I am using a C library and want to call a function with `Pointers` as arguments. It says that I need to convert `Double` to `UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>`.

So that's how far I have come:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var buffer1 = [Double]()
    var buffersize = [Int32]()
    var ar = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>.allocate(capacity: 10)
    var ar2 = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>.allocate(capacity: 2)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        randomBuffer()
        print(buffer1)
        ar.deallocate()
        ar2.deallocate()
        let grade = ar.pointee
        let isevent = ar2.pointee

        print(grade, isevent)

        let pointer = app_ios_ersatzfunktion(buffer1, buffersize, ar, ar2)
        print(pointer)
    }
    func randomBuffer()
    {
        let randomDouble = Double.random(in: -1...2)
        if buffer1.count<200{ 
        buffer1.append(randomDouble) 
        }  
        else {
            buffer1.removeFirst()
            buffer1.append(randomDouble)
        }
    }

}
```

My C code was created with Matlab and looks like this:

```
void app_ios_ersatzfunktion(const double buffer2_data[], const int buffer2_size
  [2], double *grade, double *event_found)
{
  double jerk;
  *grade = 0.0;
  *event_found = 0.0;

  jerk = (buffer2_data[buffer2_size[1] - 1] - buffer2_data[buffer2_size[1] - 2])
    / 0.01;

  if ((jerk >= 200.0) || (jerk <= -200.0)) {
    *event_found = 1.0;
    *grade = jerk / 50.0;
      }
}
```

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_c_pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly pass Swift arrays to the C function, this will pass the address of the element storage. For the “out parameters” you have to pass variables as “inout argument” with `&`:

```
let buffer2_data: [Double] = ...
let buffer2_size: [CInt] = ...

var grade: Double = 0
var event_found: Double = 0

app_ios_ersatzfunktion(buffer2_data, buffer2_size, &grade, &event_found)

print(grade, event_found)
```

Comment: Ok and how do I get access to the data in grade or event_found?

Comment: @meltemxxx: The variables are set on return from the C function.